# How to pass an observable to a child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to pass an Observable down to a child component, but I'm not able to get it working.

**parent.component.ts**:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  items$ = of([{name: "Item 1"}, {name: "Item 2"}]);
}
```

**parent.component.html**:

```
<child-component [items$]="items$"></child-component>
```

**child.component.ts**:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() items$?: Observable<Item[]>;
}
```

**child.component.html**:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Logging `items$` in the ChildComponent's `ngOnInit()` results in `undefined`. I need this instead of a hardcoded service because the `ChildComponent` should be generic and being able to take different streams. Any advice?

**Edit**: Sorry everyone I'm the perpetrator. I created an easy-to-understand example for this post (stripped from my unnecessary code). The problem was the following: in my html I accidentally added a closing tag `>` before I added the input like so:

```
<my-component
  [field1]="someVar1"
  [field2]="anotherVar2">
  [items$]="items$">
</my-component>
```

I got no error whatsoever in VSCode and the layout wasn't off... The `>` after `[field2]="anotherVar2"` caused all the trouble.

Comment: You're not passing Observable but you're using `async` pipe passing emissions from that Observable as input. If you want to pass it as an Observable just use `[items$]="items$"`

Comment: Thanks, but that still does not work :( List stays empty

Comment: Maybe you need to explicitly define the type of the source variable?
const items$: Observable<Item[]) = of([{name: "Item 1"}, {name: "Item 2"}]);

Comment: Why you don't use the `async` in the parent level anyway? That would be easier and more performant than passing this huge observable to the inner component. 

I don't know why this is not working thought, I think it should.

Comment: @stpaulis has got a point. Also, ChildComponent would be easier to unit test.

Comment: So that means creating `@Input() items?: Item[];` in the `ChildComponent` and use `[items]="items$ | async"` in the parent html?

Comment: Here is a sandbox with your code, after question edits, renders.... https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-pine-uhd4ni?file=/src/app/child/child.component.ts

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, it's time to grab a beer and celebrate the weekend I guess... I've updated the OP with the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Observable inputs can be really tricky but you can use the async pipe to get the value of the item like this example:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <h1>child</h1>
  {{data}}
  <hr/>
  `,
})

export class Child {
  name = 'Angular';
  @Input() data: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, Child],
  template: `
  <child [data]="parent$| async"></child>
  `,
})
export class Parent {
  parent$ = interval(500);
}
bootstrapApplication(Parent);
```

The full example can be found here: https://angular-d6nfhr-1lrbkb.stackblitz.io